# Level at which you start gaining Paragon experience

Tags: diablo-iii

I keep reading everywhere that you start gaining Paragon Experience, for Paragon Levels, from Level 60 - if you have Diablo 3.

Also, I keep seeing that you start earning this at maximum level, which is 70 for Reaper of Souls.

I want to know, does the bonus from the Paragon Levels kick in once you reach level 60, or only on 70?

Also, can you start gaining Paragon Experience on Level 60, or only on 70?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You start gaining paragon experience at your max level -- which is based on whether or not you have the expansion

If you *do not* have the Reaper of Souls expansion, that is level 60.

If you *do* have the expansion, then it is level 70.

The paragon levels that you can use are available to **all characters** of that game type ( Normal, Hardcore and their seasonal equivalents) -- but only characters at max level can earn the experience to get paragon levels.

Comment: The bonus you get from paragon levels earned works on any character though, so a new lvl 1 character will also have the paragon levels available that you got with your max level character.

Comment: @Arperum Yes. That is true.

Answer (score 6):

This completely depends on whether you have Reaper of souls or not. If you have it you'll start gaining Paragon EXP on level 70. If not you'll get it already at level 60.

Note that there are currently 4 separate paragon levels. One for normal characters, one for hardcore characters and also one for each seasonal hardcore and normal ones. These are all completely indivudual although the seasonal Paragon exp will be added to your normal/hardcore ones after a season is over.

Another thing to keep in mind is that All your characters have the same mode-based paragon level but you will still only be able to gain Paragon EXP once you hit max level.

For example: You have a normal Demonhunter on level 70 with a paragon level of 50. On this demonhunter you will be able to gain paragon EXP. Now at the same time you have a normal Monk on level 30. This Monk also has the paragon level 50, however you will only gain exp once you reach the level cap.

Comment: Is it not 4 separate paragon levels? Or are seasonal normal / seasonal hardcore joined together?

Comment: @TZHX Oh yeah sorry got it kinda mixed up. Lemme just fix that